# Affinity to mobile or stationary phase during column chromatography

Tags: polarity, chromatography

I have carried a column chromatography and obtained two compounds. The first one is liquid (ester) and the second one is solid (nitro) yet I know that the second compound is less polar than the first one. Why does the result differ from the knowledge about polarity (the more polar the molecule is, the slower the compound)?

Comment: I am very strongly inclined to believe that you incorrectly predicted the polarities. Just from the comparison ester versus nitro, I want to assume that the nitrocompound is more polar. Please give us structures or we cannot have the slightest of clues how to answer. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @Jan I had o-dinitrobenzene and ethyl benzoate

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know in which universe you would consider a dinitrobenzene less polar than an ethyl ester but this universe is not the correct one.

As your experimental data (the $R_\mathrm f$ values of the two eluted compounds) clearly show, the dinitrobenzene is more polar than ethyl benzoate.